Render Mermaid chart in Next.js page
Trying to display a dynamic Mermaid chart in a Next.js page without success. Renders just as plain text output. I've checked all the Mermaid code example resources I could find but no luck.
Code (pages/mermaid4.tsx):
import { InferGetStaticPropsType } from 'next';
import { GetStaticProps } from 'next';

interface Entity {
  entityid: integer;
  entityname: string;
  entityparent: integer | null;
  entitytype: string | null;
  system: integer;
  systemname: string;
  entitylevel: string;
  haschildren: boolean;
}



export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const res = await fetch('--host--');
  const jsonentities: Entity[] = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      jsonentities,
    },
  }
}

function displayChart(entities: Entity[]):string {
  // Example mermaid code
  let chart =
      `graph LR;
      A-->B;
      B-->C;
      B-->D;`;

  return chart;
}

function Display({ jsonentities }: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) {

  return (
    <div id="mermaid-chart" class="mermaid">
        { displayChart ( entities )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Display;

Output (plaintext):
graph LR; A-->B; B-->C; B-->D;

Expecting a visualised Mermaid chart such as in https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/flowchart.html
Any hints?

import { useEffect } from 'react';
import mermaid from 'mermaid';

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('--host--');
  const jsonentities = await res.json();
  return { props: { jsonentities } };
};

function Display({ jsonentities }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    mermaid.initialize({ startOnLoad: true });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="mermaid">
      {`graph LR; A-->B; B-->C; B-->D;`} {/* Example Mermaid code */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Display;


Hmmm... Got an error:Unhandled Runtime Error
Hydration failed because the server rendered HTML didn't match the client. As a result this tree will be regenerated on the client. This can happen if a SSR-ed Client Component used

I installed Nextra (https://nextra.site) on my host. Don't know if that could mess things upp. However under pages/mermaid2.mdx I have a markdown page (static page) which displays Mermaid chart just fine (```mermaid ...). The problem is that the page is static. My goal is to display Mermaid charts based on database entries fetched from server api...
